# How do I split the code behind(C#) of a WPF window into seaparate class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it a good idea to split the code behind of a WPF window to a separate class? What is the use of a partial class? Could some one explain?

Comment: what have you investigated yourself and what about that is it that you do not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate generated code from developer-written code that belong in the same class.

**There are a few things that you should be careful about when writing code for partial classes:**

- All the partial definitions must proceeded with the key word
  "Partial".
- All the partial types meant to be the part of same type must be
  defined within a same assembly and module.
- Method signatures (return type, name of the method, and parameters)
  must be unique for the aggregated typed (which was defined
  partially).
- The partial types must have the same accessibility.
- If any part is sealed, the entire class is sealed.
- If any part is abstract, the entire class is abstract.
- Inheritance at any partial type applies to the entire class.

Look at [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/partial-classes-in-C-Sharp/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN:

"When working on large projects, spreading a class over separate files allows multiple programmers to work on it simultaneously.

When working with automatically generated source, code can be added to the class without having to recreate the source file. Visual Studio uses this approach when creating Windows Forms, Web Service wrapper code, and so on. You can create code that uses these classes without having to edit the file created by Visual Studio."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a good idea to keep UI logic in the code-behind class of the view. You should use separate classes only as models. While the actual view code-behind class should contain all of the events for the view and whatever else is necessary to maintain the UI.

That being said, the UI is generally executed on just one thread, meaning as little logic as possible should be done on it to keep the responsiveness as high as possible. So the class directly linked to the window should really ideally only contain its event logic and the loading properties of the window.

Now a partial class is something that you would use to split up a auto-generated section of a class with the manually generated portion. Such as how VS splits up the window code-behind classes for Win-forms and WPF. This could also be used to split up a class so that the different developers can all specialize in one area of the class.

Comment: What? He asked if it was a good idea to split the class I gave him what I thought. He asked what a partial class was and I answered that?